# run pyqtgraph from function

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have created the following graph in pyqtgraph.  It runs fine and displays as it should.

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import csv
import itertools
from datetime import datetime as dt


app = QtGui.QApplication([])


class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
            return [dt.fromtimestamp(value) for value in values]


x_vals = [dt(2018, 7, 1, 13, 6, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 36, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 26, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 16, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 6, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 56, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 36, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 26, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 56, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 36, 38)]
y_vals =  [23.5, 20.8, 28.0, 28.1, 28.0, 27.8, 27.3, 27.2, 25.7, 24.7, 25.0, 25.0, 24.9]


date_axis = TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
plt = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems = {'bottom': date_axis})

# set properties
plt.setLabel('left', 'Temperature', units='C')
plt.setWindowTitle('Temperature over time')

plt.plot(x=[x.timestamp() for x in x_vals], y=y_vals, symbol=None, pen='r', symbolPen='r')
plt.show()  



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

However when I attempt to run it from a function, it flashes then disappears yet pyqt is still running..

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import csv
import itertools
from datetime import datetime as dt


app = QtGui.QApplication([])


class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [dt.fromtimestamp(value) for value in values]

def Gshow():
    # app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    x_vals = [dt(2018, 7, 1, 13, 6, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 36, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 26, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 16, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 6, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 56, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 36, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 26, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 56, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 36, 38)]
    y_vals =  [23.5, 20.8, 28.0, 28.1, 28.0, 27.8, 27.3, 27.2, 25.7, 24.7, 25.0, 25.0, 24.9]

    date_axis = TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')

    plt = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems = {'bottom': date_axis})

    # set properties
    plt.setLabel('left', 'Temperature', units='C')
    plt.setWindowTitle('Temperature over time')

    plt.plot(x=[x.timestamp() for x in x_vals], y=y_vals, symbol=None, pen='r', symbolPen='r')
    plt.show()  

Gshow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

How can I run the graph from the function without it crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really simple, a variable created within a function only exists until the function is finished executing, in your case plt is eliminated by what is not shown, the solution is to increase the scope of that data, a form of doing it is to return it and pass it to a variable with a greater scope.

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import csv
import itertools
from datetime import datetime as dt


app = QtGui.QApplication([])


class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [dt.fromtimestamp(value) for value in values]

def Gshow():
    # app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    x_vals = [dt(2018, 7, 1, 13, 6, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 36, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 26, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 16, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 12, 6, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 56, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 36, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 11, 26, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 56, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 46, 38), dt(2018, 7, 1, 10, 36, 38)]
    y_vals =  [23.5, 20.8, 28.0, 28.1, 28.0, 27.8, 27.3, 27.2, 25.7, 24.7, 25.0, 25.0, 24.9]

    date_axis = TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')

    plt = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems = {'bottom': date_axis})

    # set properties
    plt.setLabel('left', 'Temperature', units='C')
    plt.setWindowTitle('Temperature over time')

    plt.plot(x=[x.timestamp() for x in x_vals], y=y_vals, symbol=None, pen='r', symbolPen='r')
    plt.show()  

    return plt  # <----

var = Gshow() # <----


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: That worked great.  The only problem is that pyqtgraph has added 460mb to the 50mb exe! It's too big lol. A nice feature but too massive!

Comment: @johnashu You have to improve your imports, import complete modules usually have those problems. :)

Comment: I know I import classes or even functions as standard mainly to not have to type them out everytime!.. I only added `import pyqtgraph as pg` to the main application . It added `TKinter`, and  `tcl` for example!  I will have a look tonight and see if I can strip it down. Though imports like that can be deep inside.. Have you any experience with `PyQtChart`?

Answer (score 0):

Call Gshow() inside the main()